# Net convergence in initial topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, nets

Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *coarsest* topology on $X$ such that each
$$
f_{i}:(X, \tau) \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)
$$
is continuous. Such $\tau$ does exist and $\{f_i^{-1} (O_i) \mid i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i\}$ is its [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition). I would like to prove the following characterization, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ be a net in $X$ and $x\in X$. Then $x_d \to x$ in $\tau$ if and only if $f_i(x_d) \to f_i(x)$ for all $i \in I$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt** One direction is obvious. Let's prove the reverse. Assume $f_i(x_d) \to f_i(x)$ for all $i \in I$. Let $U$ be an open neighborhood (nbh) of $x$ in $\tau$. There exist a finite subset $J$ of $I$ and open nbh $O_i$ of $f_i (x)$ in $\tau_i$ such that
$$
\bigcap_{i\in J} f_i^{-1} (O_i) \subset U.
$$

Because $f_i (x_d) \to f_i (x)$, there is $d_i \in D$ such that $f(x_d) \in O_i$ for all $d \in D$ such that $d_i \le d$. We pick $\hat d \in D$ such that $d_i \le \hat d$ for all $i \in J$. Such $\hat d$ exists because $J$ is finite. Then
$$
x_d \in \bigcap_{i\in J} f_i^{-1} (O_i) \subset U \quad \forall d\in D \text{ such that } \hat d \le d.
$$

It follows that $x_d \to x$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Correct. Trust yourself!

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you so much for your verification!